# Measure Variance over time for an average person across a large group of people

Tags: variance, panel-data, descriptive-statistics

What would be the best way to measure variance of a metrics over time for an average person across a large group of people. For instance I have the triglycerides number for 10K people measured once a year for the past 7 years (so 70K triglyceride numbers). I want each person to be represented by one triglyceride number for the study I am doing. I was wondering if it makes sense to compute a variance over just 7 data points or if I can use all the 70K data points to compute a more accurate version of variance like average of variances or median of variance. Is there any statistical guideline, standard or practice around this?

Comment: Which kind of variance of you want? The sample variance of the average over the seven years? Then you indeed average within each year and take the sample variance of these seven averages. This is a measure of the departures of the averages of each years from the overall average of the year-wise averages. You may also consider using weights in the calculations of these averages and variances if you do not have the same number of people every year.

Comment: @Knarpie: So I am looking for one number (std dev/variance) to understand how spread out the distribution is, or would it be safe to represent each person with averages or should I consider medians, as in if the std dev is small, average is a reasonable thing to go with. So to compute the standard deviation should I consider taking the average OR median of standard deviations for each person OR take a standard deviation of the averages OR medians for each year?

Comment: I do not entirely understand what you want. If you want a good overview of individual vs. population variance I recommend you fit a linear mixed model with random intercepts for the subjects, and fixed effects for the years. The variance of that random effect represents the variability of the individual means.